# How and where can I get the continuum and/or FITS data for Jupiter and Saturn from ALMA, GMRT and VLA Telescopes?

Tags: radio-astronomy, data-analysis, jupiter, saturn, radio-telescope

I intend to process and analyze the radio images and emissions from Jupiter and Saturn. I wish to get data from ALMA, GMRT and VLA Telescopes. Requesting you to please guide me as to how do I access this data.

Answer (score 3):

Most observatories have their own separate data archives, so you’ll likely have to do three separate searches.  Here’s a query for Jupiter in the ALMA archive: https://almascience.nrao.edu/aq/?result_view=observation&sourceName=Jupiter and here’s a published paper resulting from those observations: https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2019AJ....158..139D/abstract